# Problems with the Sentinel.jl package of Julia

Tags: file-upload, julia, imagedownload, sentinel2

Following the example given in the README of the github repository of this package ([https://github.com/mhudecheck/Sentinel.jl](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)), the saveList() function creates the /.img_cache folder but then it prints a "false" value, but it stays as if it was in an eternal loop.

[image]

Do you know why could this be happening?

This is the code I am running. The json credentials are for accesing to the Sentinel-2 database of google cloud.

```
`


`using Sentinel
using GoogleCloud

creds = JSONCredentials("sentinel_2.json")
session = GoogleSession(creds, ["devstorage.full_control"])
set_session!(storage, session)

l2aList = safeList() # Outputs a DataFrame Array``
```

I have tried creating the /.img_cache for myself, not letting the program to do it by itself, but it gives the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately it is unlikely that you'll get much help on here given the need for credentials to run your code. I see you've opened an issue on the Sentinel.jl repo, you could also try the Julia Discourse or Slack (there's a climate modelling related channel which might be relevant) to see if you find any users of the package.